# Java character after compilation

Tags: java, io

Just got to know about this behavior of .class file.

Say I have this code :

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        char ch = 'A';
    }
}
```

If I compile the file and open the .class file using cavaj decompiler, it shows something like this :

```
public class Demo
{

    public Demo()
    {
    }

    public static transient void main(String args[])
    {
        byte byte0 = 65;
    }
}
```

Here, char is written as byte. But If I print this char and write a code like this :

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        char ch = 'A';
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Upon decompilation,I get this code :

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Demo
{

    public Demo()
    {
    }

    public static transient void main(String args[])
    {
        char c = 'A';
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

I would like to know two things. First, why PrintStream class has been imported explicitly by the compiler. Second, why the 'char' is written as 'char' and not as 'byte' as in previous case, or how printing a character changes the behavior ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Um, the compiler doesn't write import statements. What do you mean by "why PrintStream class has been imported explicitly by the compiler"? An import is a source-only concept.

Comment: I mean to say, why this statement is visible upon decompilation ?

Comment: That's a matter for the decompiler, not the compiler. Presumably it noticed that you're invoking a method on `PrintStream` (which is the type of `System.out`).

Comment: ok. I am clear with this reason. But what about that 'char' 'byte' thing ?

Comment: Ultimately it sounds like you're really just interested in what your decompiler is doing. Use `javap -c` to see what the *bytecode* is.

Comment: What about 'byte' thing - I think it's decompiler problem. If you look at bytecode using javap you will see, that ch variable will have type 'C' means 'char'.

Comment: when I use javap -c Demo 
it shows some processor level code which i am not able to understand. Does it really depends on the decompiler and nothing else ?